# Highlight text given String and String-Pattern

Tags: string-manipulation, formatting

given a String:

```
string = "the cat is on the mat"
```

and given a String-Pattern

```
stringPattern = "c" ~~ _ ~~ "t"
```

## question

write a function that formats its output such that every occurrence of the String-Pattern in the [`String`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/String.html) is [`Highlighted`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Highlighted.html)

```
 f[string, stringPattern]
```

[image]

Comment: Not to discourage answers here, just as a reference, there is this `ResourceFunction["HighlightText"]["This is some test text.", "test"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f = StringReplace[#, pat : #2 :> ToString[Highlighted@pat, StandardForm]] &;

f[string, stringPattern]
```

[image]

```
f[string <> " " <> string, stringPattern]
```

[image]